# How can I avoid errors when PHP, C++ and shell script try to access the same file?

Tags: php, c++, bash

Are there methods in PHP, C++ and bash scripts that can make the respective program wait its turn when accessing a file ?

I have a web-page written in PHP that gives the user the ability to input 6 values:

```
URL
URL Refresh Interval
Brightness
Color1 in hex
Color2 in hex
Color3 in hex
```

These values will be written in `configuration.txt`.

Each time the web-page is accessed `configuration.txt` gets opened, the PHP gets some values from there and then closes it.
`configuration.txt` is also opened when one or more of the above values are submitted and then it gets closed.

Next, I have a bash that regularly `wgets` the URL from `configuration.txt` and writes the output to a different file, called `url_response.txt`.

```
while [ 0 ]
do
    line=$(head -n 1 data/configuration.txt)
    wget -q -i $line -O url_response.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

This script will be put inside a C++ program.

Finally, the same C++ program will have to access `url_response.txt` to get and parse some strings from it and it will also have to access `configuration.txt` to get the three colors from it.

I am pretty sure that these 3 programs will intersect at one point and I don't want to find out what happens then.

Comment: Use a lock file. The first program creates/locks a lock file and edits `configuration.txt`. As long a the lock file exists/is locked other programs are not allowed to read or write. https://dmorgan.info/posts/linux-lock-files/

Comment: @ThomasSablik post that as an answer, deserves an upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to avoid race conditions is to use a lock file. When a program tries to read or write to `configuration.txt` it checks the lock file first.

There are two kinds of locks:

- shared lock
- exclusive lock

A program can get a **shared lock** (read lock) as long as no other program has an exclusive lock. This is used to read file. Multiple programs can read a file as long as no other program write to that file.

A program can get an **exclusive lock** (write lock) only if no other program has a lock (neither exclusive nor shared). This is used to write to a file. As long as a program is reading or writing to a file other programs are not allowed to write.

On a linux system you can use `flock` to manage file locks.

Read:

```
flock --shared lockfile -c read.sh
```

Write

```
flock --exclusive lockfile -c write.sh
```

Usually this command will wait until the lock is available. With

flock --nonblock lockfile

the command will fail immediately instead of waiting.

From manpage

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    flock [options] <file|directory> <command> [command args]
>    flock [options] <file|directory> -c <command>
>    flock [options] <file descriptor number>
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This utility manages flock(2) locks from within shell scripts or the command line.
>
> The  first  and  second  forms  wrap the lock around the executing a command, in a manner similar to su(1) or newgrp(1).  It
>   locks a specified file or directory, which is created
>          (assuming appropriate permissions), if it does not already exist.  By default, if the lock cannot be immediately acquired, flock
>   waits until the lock is available.
>
> The third form uses open file by file descriptor number.  See examples how that can be used.

[Here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) is the manpage for c++ and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) is the manpage for shell scripts.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to apply this. What do I do with `flock` ? Do I need to write it in PHP, in the C++ program, in the bash script, in all of them ? Or do I use `flock` on the file somehow and all of the above languages will know automatically how to treat the file ? And what happens if one reader can't open the file. Will it throw an error ? Will it skip over it and never read it ?

Comment: And where do I use those lines ? Who is `read.sh` and `write.sh` ?

Comment: You can call `flock` in your programs and scripts. Without `--nonblock` it will wait. With `--nonblock` it will fail with an error.

Comment: Ok. Thank you ! I still don't understand a thing, but I will search how to use flock in PHP, C++ and bash script.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to avoid one of your readers getting a partial copy of the file as it is being written?

So the usual way to avoid this issue is that when you write the file, you write it to a different name in the same folder. Then use move to replace the original file.

Unix will ensure that if there are any existing readers for the original file, the file is kept as a hidden file until they all close. Any new readers will see the newly moved file. No readers should see a broken file.

To do the same thing by modifying the file, the best you can do is keep some sort of serial number in the file. The writer should update the serial before it writes, and again after. Any reader should read the serial before and after the read. If the serial changes, then the read is invalid and should be repeated. The issue of ensuring the data is not cached also needs addressing. This is OK for occasionally updating files, but clearly it will impair the performance of the readers if the content is frequently updated.

Comment: Can I get some examples please ? Do I need to `move` files in PHP, C++, the bash script or in all of them ?